# Jailbreak iOS 6 without cydia

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, jailbreak

How do I jailbreak iOS 6.1.2 without installing Cydia?

Comment: Why would you like to jailbreak without Cydia?

Comment: You can't. But you can remove it and reverse its filesystem changes afterwards, pretty much leaving only the files required for the jailbreak to actually work.

Comment: @Robuust I am a developer that just wants to mess around and don't want all the extra cruft that Cydia brings with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a device that supports iOS 6 and is vulnerable to limera1n (iPhone 4, iPhone 3GS, or iPod touch 4th generation), you can use [redsn0w](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/tagged/redsn0w) to jailbreak 6.1.2 tethered without installing Cydia (just uncheck the "install Cydia" box during the jailbreaking process).

redsn0w hasn't been updated to automatically support 6.1.2 though, so before clicking the "Jailbreak" button, you'll need to click "Extras", click "Select IPSW", and select a copy of the 6.0 IPSW for your device. You'll also have to do the "Select IPSW" process before booting tethered (in other words, when you want to boot your device, you'll have to click "Extras", "Select IPSW", select the 6.0 IPSW, and then go back and click "Just Boot").

It's probably less fuss to just jailbreak with evasi0n, open up Cydia, let it prepare the filesystem, install OpenSSH, and then look for the "Cydia Installer" package and uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still using iOS 6 it is better to move for new iOS version.However iOS 9 is can be easily jailbreak and [download cydia](http://cydia-download.com/) for your iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch